# Tracking Mouse Hover Event on NSButton Hiding and Showing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, mouseevent, mouseover, nsbutton

I have one NSButton that i am hiding and showing with animation. first time when we move mouse cursor i am able to change the button background image by track using following methods...

```
- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent;
- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)theEvent;     
- (void)updateTrackingAreas;
```

But... here when i click the button it will hide for sometime and displays again, but the cursor is in the same button. when the button shows up again it is displaying normal mode means it not changing the background.

Any help in this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem,

By using the following method

```
 - (void)cursorUpdate:(NSEvent *)event
```